# Can the S/MIME Content Type of e-mail be explicitly defined?

Tags: c#, email, mime-types, smime, rebex

The recipient expects a signed and encrypted message with attachment.
In their specification, under the e-mail attachment section they state "The Content-Type of the MIME-Parts has to be Application/octet-stream".
Our attachment is of the required content-type. The signed only message contains different content-types but they do not seem to cause any trouble since when sending a signed only message the recipient is able to parse our message and sends an ack.
When encrypting the message the resulting Content-Type is `Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime;`.
After contacting the recipient, they were able to provide us with the error message of their automated system which reads: `Unknown Email-ContentType: application/pkcs7-mime`
Their error message leaves me to believe that other than the attachment-type the e-mail content-type needs to be of octet stream as well.
I'm using C# with Rebex is it possible to force a specific content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing specific content types is possible using Rebex API (at least in this case), but you have to use the low-level MIME API. So if you are currently using the `MailMessage` class, you might use this approach:

```
using Rebex.Mail;
using Rebex.Mime;
using Rebex.Mime.Headers;
...


var message = new MailMessage();
...
message.Sign(...);
message.Encrypt(...);

MimeMessage mime = message.ToMimeMessage();
mime.ContentType = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
mime.Save("message.eml");
```

However, be aware that this will result in a message that appears to only contain binary data, and it will most likely not be recognized as an S/MIME message by common mail software and libraries, including Rebex Secure Mail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've reached at that point to and seems the most logical interpretation of their specifications. Seeing the binary file in my mail client as an attachment is what confused me making me think I did something really wrong.